# How to decrypt AES-GCM encoded message using AAD in Java

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, aes

I have some existing C++ code that uses openssl to send an encrypted message.

I'm writing a new Java based client to receive this message and cannot properly decrypt the message. I'm getting `javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch` errors.

The message is structured like this:

```
header info (21 bytes)
nonce (12 bytes)
tag data (16 bytes)
encrypted payload (n bytes)
```

The header and nonce bytes are input as Additional Authenticated Data.

The Java code to decrypt:

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
                 aesKey,
                 new GCMParameterSpec( 96, packet.getNonce() ));

    cipher.updateAAD( packet.getHeaderAndNonce() );
    return cipher.doFinal( packet.getEncryptedData() );
```

I see mention in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26370130/212589 that in Java the **tag data is added at the end of the cipher text** when encrypting. I have tried changing `packet.getEncryptedData()` to return the following:

1. tag data (16 bytes) + encrypted payload (n bytes)
2. encrypted payload (n bytes) + tag data (16 bytes)

but both cases fail with the same bad tag exception.

What am I doing wrong?

For reference, here is the C++ code that is doing the encryption:

```
const unsigned int NONCE_LEN = 12;
const unsigned int TAG_DATA_LEN = 16;
const unsigned int DATA_PACKET_HEADER_LEN = 49;
const unsigned int DATA_NONCE_OFFSET = 21;
const unsigned int DATA_TAG_DATA_OFFSET = 33;

std::array<byte, NONCE_LEN> randomNonce = getRandomNonce();
std::copy(randomNonce.begin(), randomNonce.end(), _data.begin() + DATA_NONCE_OFFSET);

EVP_EncryptInit_ex(cipherContext, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), nullptr, encryptionKey.data(), randomNonce.data());

int outlen;
EVP_EncryptUpdate(cipherContext, nullptr, &outlen, _data.data(), DATA_PACKET_HEADER_LEN - TAG_DATA_LEN);    
EVP_EncryptUpdate(cipherContext, _data.data() + DATA_PACKET_HEADER_LEN, &outlen,
        _payloadPlaintext.data(), _payloadPlaintext.size() );

EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(cipherContext, nullptr, &outlen);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(cipherContext, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, TAG_DATA_LEN, &_data[DATA_TAG_DATA_OFFSET]);
```

Comment: Yes, Java puts the tag at the end of the ciphertext; that matches only your #2 not #1. But for a tag length of 16 bytes = 128 bits, specifying 96 in `GCMParameterSpec` is wrong; see [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/spec/GCMParameterSpec.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,byte%5B%5D). PS: for GCM you don't need to put nonce in the AAD, it is implicitly authenticated.

Comment: oh man, I was using the nonce length there. You are correct, changing that to 128 and moving the tag data to the end worked, thanks! Also, good to know about the nonce in the AAD, unfortunately, I can't change the C++ side of things, so I'll have to continue to include it on the java side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues with my solution (see @dave_thompson_085's comment)

1. The tag length parameter passed to `GCMParameterSpec` was wrong. It should be 128
2. The Java decrypt assumes the tag data is at the end of the ciphertext, so in my case I had to move the tag data bytes from the beginning.